# Unknown error message

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when trying to output to a text file:

```
 io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable.
```

My code:

```
    def PostCodeStore(self):
       #Opens the Postcode file in append mode
       file = open("PostCode_File.txt", "r")

       PostCodeValue= PostCodeVar.get()

       #Writes the Postcode value to the file and adds a new line
       file.write(PostCodeValue + "\n")

       #Closes the file so it saves the value
       file.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you can't write to a file opened with `'r'`. You must open with `'a'`. From the documentation:

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second argument is another string containing a few characters describing the way in which the file will be used. **mode can be 'r' when the file will only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing.** The mode argument is optional; 'r' will be assumed if it’s omitted.
>
> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary files.

This is a common issue, and (as seen in the docs), one that can cause some problems when writing cross-compatible programs, as Windows has a different set of permissions for binary files. You are likely not going to be working with binary files (maybe zipfiles), so I wouldn't worry about that too much. Just remember:

```
'w'  # Writing
'r'  # Reading (default)
'a'  # Appending
'r+' # Read/Write
```

I believe I understand your problem correctly. That is, that your program wants to write many lines, one at a time (append). If you don't want to do that and just want a single entry in the file with a newline, you will want to use `'w'`.

Also (and as a side note), Python class names generally start with a capital letter. That's why `PostCodeValue` shows up with different formatting. Conventionally, a variable like this should be named with small letters and underscores, such as `post_code_value`.

Comment: OP want's append, not truncate and overwrite

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong

```
   file = open("PostCode_File.txt", "r")#Opens the Postcode file in append mode
```

With `r` as mode, you open the file read-only, not append. That'd be `a`.